# Creating different file extensions in Python

Tags: python, .net, file

I recently got a data processing project, I am given a program which is written in dot net. Its a typical program to collect data from user and store in a file with `.pcxm` extension . But its ugly and unimpressive. It doesn't even support copy/paste. So I decided to rewrite the same program in python. Everything is easy to do and I have almost completed my program but here is one and only problem I got. The project provider wants a data file in `.pcxm` format only. I don't know how to create data file with this extension. Now my question goes, does anybody please tell me if I can create same kind of file(`.pcxm`) with python.? Any kind of suggestion will really be appreciated. I desperately need the help.

P.S. I reverse compiled [this](https://anonfiles.com/file/bd1a8a50615822a944641f25f27abf8a) and got source file.

Comment: Search [here](https://pypi.python.org/) if there is a python package for your needs.

Comment: info about the format in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/671282)

Comment: @goncalopp: I already tried the answer but didn't help its a different topic.. The page covers only image type of pcxm file. In my case the file contains data not images so its of no use.. I can upload the program and the file if you wish to have a look..

Comment: Do you have a reference to what parts of the pcxm format you need? It could be that there is no 100% implementation in Python. What does the .net program use? Do you have the sources of it? Could you upload the sources?

Comment: hello @User, I have uploaded the program [here](https://anonfiles.com/file/bd1a8a50615822a944641f25f27abf8a), it is a 2.16 mb compressed file. But it is not a source. I don't have anything to do with program. I just only need a way to create the file as .pcxm file if that is possible. Please tell me if anything is possible with this scenario.

Comment: After digging a while on the internet, I successfully decompiled the vb program. The program uses sqlce as a database and use tripleDESCrypto Service to encrypt the datafile stored in database. The source code is [here](https://anonfiles.com/file/c3592ed0a85c5cb925d235cad5df929a) .I saw that there are tools to convert .net source file to python source file but I am not sure if the encryption mechanism can also be transformed. Please suggest something.!!